# jHtmlArea "enter" key generated HTML not cross browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jhtmlarea

I'm trying to use the jHtmlArea WYSIWYG editor based on jQuery.

My problem is that the behaviour of the editor towards the "enter key" is different from browser to browser, for instance, IE renders a **p** tag, Chrome renders a **div** tag and Firefox renders a **br** tag.

What's causing this? How can I make this consistent?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you log a bug? http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic That would be my first step.

Comment: no one is getting an answer there, I checked that before coming here.